# WPF application in a one window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, directx, backgroundworker

1. I would like to make an application in a one window using XAML.
   It should be like a slideshow with next and back button. One idea is to make 4 panels and have just one enable at the time. Is there any other way to do this? Like dynamic loading of other XAML?
2. is it the BackgroundWorker mandatory to use with WPF (hence is DirectX rendered there's almost no GUI lags) ?

Comment: This question covers a lot of ground and leaves a lot of uncertainty about what you're trying to accomplish. If you provide more detail you're likely to get better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out other soulution: Tab Control
IMO better - more flexible

Answer (score 1):

1. You can do it with Pages that you can show in a window. Just create a window for every page and change the root tag to Page.
2. It should be used if you want to perform a long running, non-UI related task, to prevent locking the UI.

Comment: I agree that using pages seems to be a great fit, just handle the page navigation to simulate slides.

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be achieved fairly easily with a [VirtualizingStackPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.virtualizingstackpanel.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

1.You can use ItemTemplate and load any one you wish on your click event.

2.BackgroundWorker is always a better choice to use.